# How to efficiently create D3D Buffer from std::deque

Tags: c++, memory, directx, deque

It is known, that `std::deque< T >` consists of chunks of data (array of arrays or list of arrays, I don't know). If size of `T` is small enough, then each chunk commonly created having a size 4k. It is true for (I believe) *libc++* and *libstdc++* (correct me if I am wrong). 4k is a page size for *x86*/*x64* platforms (I believe).

I collect the data one by one and store it into the `std::deque`. At the end I should to pass it to the DirectX buffer using its API.

Can I get an access to individual chunks of the `std::deque` in general to load them each at once (without implementation details fileds), but not values of type `T` one by one?

It would be great to have such an interface of `std::deque`, which allows to achieve desired inherently. Say, `std::unordered_{set,map}` have buckets (w/o access to them). Newly developed design of tries allows to move individual nodes from one to another container etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you check for chunks yourself using pointer arithmetics? Here's an example that fills an `std::deque` and then gives iterators to the beginning of every chunk:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef int MyType;
    std::deque<MyType> myInts(10000);
    //fill the array
    int count = 0;
    std::generate(myInts.begin(), myInts.end(), [&](){ return ++count; });

    //chunks' beginnings container
    std::vector<std::deque<MyType>::iterator> myIntsChunks;
    myIntsChunks.push_back(myInts.begin());
    for(std::deque<MyType>::iterator it = myInts.begin()+1; it != myInts.end(); it++)
    {
        if(&(*(it-1)) != ((&(*(it)))-1)) //if this element's pointer isn't right after the previous element's pointer
        {
            myIntsChunks.push_back(it);
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"I found " << myIntsChunks.size() << " chunk(s)." << std::endl;
    std::for_each(myIntsChunks.begin(), myIntsChunks.end(),
                  [&myInts](const std::deque<MyType>::iterator& it)
    {
        std::cout<<"Chunk starts at " << std::distance(myInts.begin(),it) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

If you change that `std::deque` to `std::vector`, you'll get only one chunk!

Comment: You need to append `myInts.end()` to stay generic. It is general pattern for "proxy"-containers.

Comment: @Orient I'm appending `myInts.begin()` at the beginning to include the first chunk. `end()` is not part of the deque and is not a chunk. I consider dereferencing every element of the chunks safe, and by adding ints that's not anymore the case. I guess that depends on the convention you want to follow.

Comment: But I need the ranges of elements to copy. Or pointer to first element + (current) chunk size. Given the `myIntsChunks` I can get all the sizes of chunks except the last one. Last one in the case is special case. And therefore requires special handling. "To stay generic" is quite big acquisition for that small payment.

Comment: Also your solution is `N`, but can be `log(N) * M`, where `M` is number of chunks.

Comment: @Orient I can still think of pros and cons of adding the `end()`. I'll just keep the example simple. Also about performance, this is just an example that I wrote in 2 minutes. Feel free to optimize it :)